# What are ADO.NET output parameters

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am reading Murachs ADO.NET 4 database programming book. In chapter 7 they talk about output parameters. I have never seen this before when programming data readers. The book glazes over the topic and so does the internet. My question is what are output parameters and what cases will you use output parameters.

Here is the example in the book:

```
SELECT @Name = Name, @Address = Address1, @Address2 = Address2, @City = City
FROM Vendors
WHERE VendorID = @VendorID
```

As you can see there are parameters in the select area of this query. How does this work? I have never seen them there before. I have always seen them in the where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got a sproc where you want to return multiple scalar values without having to put them into a result table you can use multiple output parameters.

A T-SQL context (be it a stored procedure or executing SQL directly) accepts in parameters, and returns any or all of the following:

1. A resultset (comprised of zero or more tables)
2. A return code or value
3. Output parameters
4. Messages

In the T-SQL you posted, it means rather than returning a table in the resultset, the code is storing singular scalar field values in T-SQL variables (because `VendorID` is a primary-key, only 1 row will be returned), and presumably those variables are bound as output parameters and thus accessible by the calling SQL client.

In a way, the output of a T-SQL script can be compared to a C# function, which can output by setting `out` method parameters, providing a return value, and writing to `stdout` or `stderr` (or any other non-local, in-scope resource).